# sql server connectivity issue

Tags: c#, sql-server

If I am trying to run service from local machine - I get message as

> Login failed for user ''. The user is not associated with trusted
>   SQL Server connection.

whereas, If I run the service from server - it works fine.

I am also able to connect to server from SQL Server - works fine too

Only while debugging I am getting error

Any guess why ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Same user account for the service on both machines?

Answer (score 0):

Things to check:

- Is the service on your local machine using a different connection string to your service from the server (check the .config files)
- Is the service on your local machine running under a different user account then the service on the server

Comment: Hi Andrew, Thanks for comments.
so -- Connectionstring is same on server and local
-- locally, I am using my AD ID whereas on the server - I am using service account.

Note: My AD id has permission and I am able to connect to sql server from its UI 

by any chance - can we use service a/c to test from local ?

Comment: Also, I do not get message Login failed for user "user ID" -- it simply says - Login failed for user ''

Comment: Have you configure your connection string on your app/webconfig?